# Easiest way to make a CSS page transition

Tags: jquery, css, layout, slider, transition

This is my first time posting, but I'm trying to make this work. What's wrong? Here's the html, css, and js.

```
    <div class="pt-wrapper">
    <div class="pt-trigger-container">
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="1" data-goto="1">Go to page 1</button>
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="2" data-goto="2">Go to page 2</button>
    </div>


    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1">
        <h1><strong>Page 1</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2">
        <h1><strong>Page 2</strong></h1>
    </div>
</div>

     var PageTransitions = (function() {

    var $main = $( '#pt-main' ),
        $pages = $main.children( 'div.pt-page' ),
        $iterate = $( '#iterateEffects' ),
        animcursor = 1,
        pagesCount = $pages.length,
        current = 0,
        isAnimating = false,
        endCurrPage = false,
        endNextPage = false,
        animEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
            'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
            'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
            'animation' : 'animationend'
        },
        // animation end event name
        animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
        // support css animations
        support = Modernizr.cssanimations;

    function init() {

        $pages.each( function() {
            var $page = $( this );
            $page.data( 'originalClassList', $page.attr( 'class' ) );
        } );

        $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' );

        $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu( {
            animationClasses : { in : 'dl-animate-in-2', out : 'dl-animate-out-2' },
            onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                nextPage( el.data( 'animation' ) );
            }
        } );

        $iterate.on( 'click', function() {
            if( isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            if( animcursor > 67 ) {
                animcursor = 1;
            }
            nextPage( animcursor );
            ++animcursor;
        } );

    }

    function nextPage(options ) {
        var animation = (options.animation) ? options.animation : options;

        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }

        isAnimating = true;

        var $currPage = $pages.eq( current );

        if(options.showPage){
            if( options.showPage < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                current = options.showPage;
            }
            else {
                current = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            if( current < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                ++current;
            }
            else {
                current = 0;
            }
        }

        var $nextPage = $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' ),
            outClass = '', inClass = '';

        switch( animation ) {

            case 1:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToLeft';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight';
                break;
            case 2:
                outClass = 'pt-page-moveToRight';
                inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft';
                break;
        }

        $currPage.addClass( outClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
            $currPage.off( animEndEventName );
            endCurrPage = true;
            if( endNextPage ) {
                onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
            }
        } );

        $nextPage.addClass( inClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
            $nextPage.off( animEndEventName );
            endNextPage = true;
            if( endCurrPage ) {
                onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
            }
        } );

        if( !support ) {
            onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
        }

    }

    function onEndAnimation( $outpage, $inpage ) {
        endCurrPage = false;
        endNextPage = false;
        resetPage( $outpage, $inpage );
        isAnimating = false;
    }

    function resetPage( $outpage, $inpage ) {
        $outpage.attr( 'class', $outpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) );
        $inpage.attr( 'class', $inpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) + ' pt-page-current' );
    }

    init();

    return { 
        init : init,
        nextPage : nextPage,
    };

    })();


   .pt-page-moveToLeft {
    -webkit-animation: moveToLeft .6s ease both;
    animation: moveToLeft .6s ease both;
   }

   .pt-page-moveFromLeft {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromLeft .6s ease both;
    animation: moveFromLeft .6s ease both;
   }

   .pt-page-moveToRight {
    -webkit-animation: moveToRight .6s ease both;
    animation: moveToRight .6s ease both;
   }

   .pt-page-moveFromRight {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromRight .6s ease both;
    animation: moveFromRight .6s ease both;
    }


    html, body { height: 100%; }

.pt-perspective {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -moz-perspective: 1200px;
    perspective: 1200px;
}

.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pt-page-current,
.no-js .pt-page {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}

.no-js body {
    overflow: auto;
}

.pt-page-ontop {
    z-index: 999;
}

/* Text Styles, Colors, Backgrounds */

.pt-page h1 {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4.4em;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 12%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-spacing: -0.3em;
}

.pt-page h1 span {
    font-family: 'Satisfy', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40%;
    text-transform: none;
    word-spacing: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.pt-page h1 strong {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.pt-page-1 {
    background: #0ac2d2;
}

.pt-page-2 {
    background: #7bb7fa;
}

.pt-page-3 {
    background: #60d7a9;
}

.pt-page-4 {
    background: #fdc162;
}

.pt-page-5 {
    background: #fd6a62;
}

.pt-page-6 {
    background: #f68dbb;
}

/* Triggers (menu and button) */

.pt-triggers {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 12%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 130px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); 
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.no-js .pt-triggers {
    display: none;
}

.pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper button,
.pt-touch-button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.pt-touch-button {
    background: #fff;
    color: #aaa;
}

.pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper button {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.pt-touch-button:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.touch .pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper {
    display: none;
}

.pt-message {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #da475c;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.pt-message p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.no-cssanimations .pt-message {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 47.4375em) {
    .pt-page h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
    }

    .pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 45.9em) {
    .pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper li a {
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper li.dl-back:after, .dl-menuwrapper li > a:not(:only-child):after {
        line-height: 24px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 38em) { 
    .pt-triggers .dl-menuwrapper {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a full-page transition slide. Please help! I'm doing this based on the CoDrops Typanus Page transitions.

I'm trying to only show one "page" at a time. On the click of the pt-trigger button, I wish to have a transition that will take me to the other "page" by sliding it in from the right.

Comment: It would be good if you could post more information about what precisely is not working for you, and explain some of the things you've done. That will make it easier for other people to assist you with your issue

Comment: Okay, thanks. I edited a bit. And either the page doesn't' show at all or both show.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are open to AngularJS or not. But if you are, you can try simple Angular animation which works by just adding angular and angular animation lib.

Try out example at http://plnkr.co/edit/SZFQ0waEpIc6v5t5SDJT?p=preview

Check style.css file.

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example3-production</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <div class="pt-wrapper" ng-init="page=true">
    <div class="pt-trigger-container">
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="1" data-goto="1" ng-click="page=true">Go to page 1</button>
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="2" data-goto="2" ng-click="page=false">Go to page 2</button>
    </div>


    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1 sample-show-hide" ng-show="page" style="clear:both;">
        <h1><strong>Page 1</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2 sample-show-hide" ng-show="!page" style="clear:both;">
        <h1><strong>Page 2</strong></h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css:

```
/* Put your css in here */

.sample-show-hide {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Don't you think Angular JS would be too heavy for this? Or is that something that would be well suited? Also, what would be the CSS for the slide effect?

Comment: AngularJS is not just animation lib. It has other benefits such as live binding, routes etc..It is great for single page application. Here is better example for all your slide animations. [A Scalable Approach to Page Transitions in AngularJS](http://phillippuleo.com/articles/scalable-approach-page-transitions-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

The `codrops` library is awesome but their implementation of source code is poor.

All you have do for creating page transitions is use their `animation.css` file.
Extract their required animation classes and use they by writing little bit of jQuery.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb5nacc8/1/) example.